# How to override DNS in HTTP connections in Html Unit

Tags: java, dns, htmlunit

I want to override the DNS resolution when using Html Unit, so that I can test an explicit server behind a load balancer. This should be done without changing the etc/hosts file.

This question got's an answer how to solve that task with plain java: [How to override DNS in HTTP connections in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350150/how-to-override-dns-in-http-connections-in-java)

But I need a solution with Html Unit.

Html Unit uses the apache httpclient.
Is it possible to change the connection manager of the httpclient?
(see other question above)

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().set???
```

Comment: *"Is it possible to change the connection manager of the httpclient?"* Isn't that exactly what the [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35327982/5221149) does?

Comment: Not really, because I can't find a way how to achieve that when using Html Unit. So if you can tell me how to change the connection manager with Html Unit that would help, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the default [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) used by [`WebClient`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html), call [`setWebConnection()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#setWebConnection-com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConnection-) with a custom subclass of [`HttpWebConnection`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/HttpWebConnection.html) where you override [`createHttpClient()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/HttpWebConnection.html#createHttpClient--).

Comment: Thank's I think that's it. I just missed createHttpClient().