# Temporarily resolve domain to localhost for testing in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dns, hosts

Using spring boot I build an application which does HTTP request to an external distant service. For testing, I want to mock this external service instead of doing calls to the real service. When running full end-2-end test, the code still executes the HTTP requests, but I want it to call instead my mock server (in which I can check that the calls were made correctly).

Say the calls are made to `api.example.com`. Can I, using Java / Spring / JBehave programmatically and temporarily add a line to the hosts file or equivalent behavior in the JVM so that `api.example.com` resolves to `localhost`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1: Spring profile**

Assuming `api.example.com` is defined in your spring  `application.properties`, the most common behavior is to override this property using the [spring boot fallback mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) associated to spring profile.

For example assuming `api.example.com` is associated to the property `api.host` key, You could create a spring profile `integration-testing` and its associated application properties files `application-integration-testing.properties` under `src/test/resources`. This file will contain `api.host=localhost` whereas the production `application.properties` contains `api.host=api.example.com`.

You annotate your test with `@ActiveProfiles("integration-testing")` and voila, `api.host` value will be `localhost` but only for testing.

**Solution 2: Custom DNS resolver**

It does not seems possible to have a custom resolver with the default implementation (HttpURLConnection). You can use a `RestTemplate` with an implementation of [ClientHttpRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestFactory.html) which allows a custom DNS resolver eg. the Apache HttpClient [HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html), [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35327982/564005) for more detail.

**Solution 3: Mock Rest template**

You can use a `RestTemplate` mock using [MockRestServiceServer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html). This solution does not involve a real http server.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this approach is what I had planned if I find no direct way of redirecting the calls with the real URL. I would rather have the calls done with the correct URL if possible.

Comment: Which http client are you using? It may allow to define a custom DNS resolver.

Comment: I'm using RestTemplate

Comment: It does not seems possible to have a custom resolver with the default implementation (`HttpURLConnection`). I see 2 possible solutions: 1) Use a RestTemplate mock using [`MockRestServiceServer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html). This solution does not involve a real http server 2) Use a RestTemplate with a `ClientHttpRequestFactory` which allows a custom DNS resolver eg. the `Apache HttpClient` `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35327982/564005)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Could you add this to your answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I have added the 2 solutions to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I would say, you can use MockServer, and using RestAssured framework by which you can trace the call and redirect to mock server.