# DNS lookup while starting Spring Boot Application in IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Does IntelliJ provide any way by which we can look up for DNS from .properties file while starting the application(Spring Boot - Gradle) so that all inbound API URL's call go to the replaced DNS IP?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Be default, Spring Boot will bind the embedded web server to all network interfaces (0.0.0.0). You can restrict this, but it doesn't sound like this is what you are looking for. Could you expand on what you are want to achieve? Maybe you meant _outbound_ instead of _inbound_?

Comment: Suppose in properties, there are 50 API's URL out of which 20 URLs are pointing to IP1(192.16.1.100) and 30 URLs pointing to IP2(192.16.1.101). Instead of actual IPs, I am using their DNS name as name1 and name2 respectively. While starting the application I want the DNS names to get replaced by their respective IPs before starting itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question right, you can make use of [DnsResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/remoting/dns/DnsResolver.html) .You will probably be using, lets say, a restTemplate to make the network call, you can enhance its HttpClient by customizing its DnsResolver.

```
class RestTemplateWithDnsOverrideConfig {
@Bean
RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate(
            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                    HttpClientBuilder.create()
                            .setDnsResolver(createDnsResolver())
                            .build()
            )
    )
}

private DnsResolver createDnsResolver() {
    return new DnsResolver() {
        @Override
        InetAddress[] resolve(String host) throws UnknownHostException {
            return [Inet4Address.getByAddress([127, 0, 0, 1] as byte[])]
        }
    }
}
```

}

Also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35327982) answer